# function returning same value after pass by copy in java

Tags: java

I have a code as below where I am swapping the `Instance variables` of class in `Function` called `SwapNames`

```
public class Sam3 
{
    public String FirstName, LastName;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Sam3 objSam1 = new Sam3();
        Sam3 objSam2 = new Sam3();

        objSam1.FirstName = "Name1";
        objSam2.LastName  = "Name2";        

        System.out.print(objSam1.FirstName + " " + objSam2.LastName);

        SwapNames(objSam1, objSam2);

        System.out.print(objSam1.FirstName + " " + objSam2.LastName);
    }

    public static void SwapNames(Sam3 obj1, Sam3 obj2)
    {   
        Sam3 temp = obj2; 
        obj2 = obj1;
        obj1 = temp;

        obj1.FirstName = "First Name";
        obj2.LastName  = "Last Name";
    }
}
```

Now the Output of the Code is as below

```
Name1 Name2
Name1 Name2
```

The thing which I dont understand is I swapped the values in `obj1 and obj2` - References made to their `classes`.After that I am changing the value.

Why the code is not taking effect.

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void SwapNames(Sam3 obj1, Sam3 obj2)
{   
    Sam3 temp = obj2; 
    obj2 = obj1;
    obj1 = temp;

    obj1.FirstName = "First Name"; //<-- is actually objSam2 
    obj2.LastName  = "Last Name";  //<-- is actually objSam1
}
```

to see what's going on:

```
class Test{

    public int i=2;
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test t1 = new Test();
    t1.i=0;

    Test t2 = new Test();
    t2.i=1;


    System.out.println(t1.i+" "+t1);
    System.out.println(t2.i+" "+t2);

    test(t1,t2);

    System.out.println(t1.i+" "+t1);
    System.out.println(t2.i+" "+t2);



}

public static void test(Test a, Test b){
    Test swap=a;
    a=b;
    b=swap;

    System.out.println(a.i+" "+a);
    System.out.println(b.i+" "+b);
}

}
/*
output:
0 Test@3c56b64c
1 Test@60da5686
1 Test@60da5686
0 Test@3c56b64c
0 Test@3c56b64c
1 Test@60da5686
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

*In Java everything is pass by value*.

When you call `SwapNames(objSam1, objSam2);` reference `objSam1` and `objSam2` will be copied to the method `SwapNames` parameter `obj1` and `obj2`.

so after swap reference value of `obj1` and `obj2` will be swapped not `objSam1` and `objSam2`.

`objSam1` and `objSam2` is still holding the old reference Object. So that does not effect anything.

---

For better clarification

```
Sam3 temp = obj2; 
obj2 = obj1;
obj1 = temp;
```

If you print the value of FirstName & LastName of the Object.

```
System.out.print(obj1.FirstName + " " + obj2.LastName);
```

you will see result will be `Name2 Name1`

*As because obj1 is now referencing the second Obeject and obj2 is referencing first object.*

Comment: Thanks for Reply. If I put objSam1.FirstName  = "Name2" with out swapping its taking effect.But why If I do a swap and change the value it is not taking effect

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there are two Sam3 object reference variable 
which contains object of Sam3 class.

for objSam1 first Instance of Same3 [remember Sam3 
contains two instance variable FirstName, LastName]
    objSam1.FirstName = "Name1";
    objSam1.LastName = null; // this is default value if you don't set or initialize

for objSam2 which is second Instance of Sam3 [ remember Sam3 
  class contains two instance variable FirstName, LastName]
  objSam2.FirstName = null; //this is default if we don't initialize .FirstName     
  objSam2.LastName = "Name2";

Now after calling swaping method objects are changed but you are changing
   objSam2.FirstName = "First Name"; 
//previously FirstName was null and there is no change in .LastName  (see code above)

and for 
   objSam1.LastName = "Last Name"; 
// previously it was null and there is no change in .FirstName  (see above code)

So the computer is giving correct answer.